# Capybara: use domain instead of IP-based URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

My Rails app is a Facebook app and FB requires a domain as application URL (i.e., not an IP with port).

Therefore, I'd like Capybara to use

```
http://myapp.test
```

as root URL instead of

```
http://127.0.0.1:53386
```

How can I set up this environment?

Answer (score 1):

In your spec_helper or env.rb

```
Capybara.app_host = 'myapp.test'
```

Comment: I get this error:

Failure/Error: visit '/'
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       Component returned failure code: 0x804b000a (NS_ERROR_MALFORMED_URI) [nsIIOService.newURI]